# JS logical operators

Tags: javascript

```
var 
            type = 'foo',
            type2 = 'bar',
            result = 0;

        type == 'foo' && result++;
        console.log(result); // 1
        !type == 'foo' || result++;
        console.log(result); // 2
        type == 'foo' && type2 == 'bar' && result++;
        console.log(result); //3
        type == 'foo' && type2 == 'bar' && result == 3 && (result=0); //parentheses avoid "invalid assignment left-hand side" error
        console.log(result); //0
        type == 'OOF' || result++; //equivalent: type != 'OOF' && result++;
        console.log(result); //1
```

in what order it is works?

```
            type == 'foo' && result++;
        !type == 'foo' || result++;
```

full article(https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/conditionals.html)

Comment: If `type == 'foo'` is true, then only `result++` will be incremented...In `||` case irrespective of the first condition is met, `result` will be incremented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break it down:

```
type == 'foo' && result++;
```

Due to short circuit evaluation, the second part `result++` only gets evaluated if `type == 'foo'`.  Fairly straightforward case, right?  Lets look at the second condition:

```
!type == 'foo' || result++;
```

This likely does not do what you think it will.  You're evaluating type to a boolean, which in this case, any non-empty string will return true.  You negate that value, so you get false.  Comparing false to `'foo'` gets you false.  In order to short circuit that expression, the first part would have to be true, but it is false, so in short, `result++` will always be evaluated.

You probably meant the following:

```
!(type == 'foo') || result++
```

Or equally acceptable:

```
type != 'foo' || result++
```

Lets take a look at the following:

```
type == 'foo' && type2 == 'bar' && result == 3 && (result=0)
```

If type is foo, then it evaluates the next section, so `type2 == 'bar'`.  If that is true as well, then it will evaluate `result == 3`.  If that is true, then result gets *assigned* to 0 since you aren't checking equivalence.  So essentially, if type is 'foo' and type2 is 'bar' and result is 3, set result to 0.

It is important to know how it works, but don't ever add increment or assign statements in conditions in real world code.  They are notoriously difficult to spot even if *you* wrote it if enough time passes since you wrote it.

Hope that helps.